# How to clone relative to an entity's coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This is kind of a sequel to the other post I made, 'Scoreboard/Cloning Help' and someone said maybe I could clone stuff relative to an entity's coordinates, I thought it was an amazing idea, but he didn't post any command to go with it.

If you guys could help my find how to do that, that would be awesome.

Comment: Could you use "/execute @e[type=Entity] /clone (Co-ords of thing to be cloned) ~ ~ ~

Answer (score 1):

Much like what Haroun Mohamed-Fakier said, all you need to do is use the `/execute` command.

The command would look something like this.

```
/execute @e[type=Zombie] ~ ~ ~ /clone ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~2 ~
```

This command will target all Zombies and clone the block below them to right above them.

Hope this helped and if you have any questions just comment and I'll do my best to answer.